# Get hashcode of a HashSet based on the items present in the HashSet

Tags: c#, hashset, hashcode, gethashcode

I have a `HashSet<T>` and I want to get the hashcode of the `HashSet<T>` based on the items it contains. I am trying to identify a `HashSet<T>` based on it's values. I know I can use set operations to check if two `HashSet<T>`'s are equal. I need a hashcode because I want to use memoization in a function which takes a `HashSet<T>` as an argument.

```cs
HashSet<string> one = new HashSet<string>();
one.Add("java");
Console.WriteLine(one.GetHashCode());

HashSet<string> two = new HashSet<string>();
two.Add("java");
Console.WriteLine(two.GetHashCode() == one.GetHashCode()); 
// I want the hash code to be same for one and two,
// since they both contain the same strings.
```

Is there a way to identify a `HashSet<T>` based on it's values without overriding the `GetHashCode` method? If there isn't one could you please provide the override implementation for `GetHashCode` of a `HashSet<T>` of strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HashSet<T>` has a static [`CreateSetComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.createsetcomparer) method that could solve your problem if it worked correctly, but [it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842499/hashsett-createsetcomparer-cannot-specify-iequalitycomparert-is-there-an).

```
IEqualityComparer<HashSet<string>> comparer = HashSet<string>.CreateSetComparer();
Console.WriteLine(comparer.GetHashCode(two) == comparer.GetHashCode(one));
```

This will print `true` in your example, but if the two hashsets are configured with a non-default comparer, for example [`StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase), and contain items that are different according to the default comparer, for example `"java"` and `"Java"`, it will print `false`.

The `HashSetEqualityComparer<T>` class below is aware of the [`Comparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.comparer) of each hashset, and produces identical hashcodes for hashsets that contain the same elements, regardless of the order that they were inserted in the hashsets.

```
public class HashSetEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<HashSet<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(HashSet<T> x, HashSet<T> y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (x is null || y is null) return false;
        if (!ReferenceEquals(x.Comparer, y.Comparer)) return false;
        return x.SetEquals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(HashSet<T> hashSet)
    {
        if (hashSet is null) return 0;
        HashCode hashCode = new();
        foreach (int value in hashSet
            .Select(x => hashSet.Comparer.GetHashCode(x)).Order())
        {
            hashCode.Add(value);
        }
        return hashCode.ToHashCode();
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
HashSetEqualityComparer<string> comparer = new();
Console.WriteLine(comparer.GetHashCode(two) == comparer.GetHashCode(one));
```

The [`HashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode) is a built-in `struct`, that is used for combining multiple values into a single hashcode.

Sorting the hashcodes of the contained elements is a relatively expensive O(n log n) operation. In case paying this performance cost is not desirable, you can get a valid hashcode faster using the [XOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-) technique:

```
public int GetHashCode(HashSet<T> hashSet)
{
    if (hashSet is null) return 0;
    int hashCode = 0;
    foreach (T item in hashSet)
    {
        hashCode = hashCode ^ HashCode.Combine(hashSet.Comparer.GetHashCode(item));
    }
    return hashCode;
}
```

The quality of the resulting hashcode might not be as good though. The [`HashCode.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode.combine#system-hashcode-combine-1(-0)) method with a single argument can be used in order to diffuse the hashcode of each element across a large range. Which improves the quality of the resulting hashcode in case, for example, that the elements are small integer numbers.

Comment: Your assertion that there is a bug in `CreateSetComparer` is not entirely true. It does work if the comparers are non-default https://dotnetfiddle.net/2qz085 it only doesn't work if you create a *new* set using that comparer, or if the two sets use different comparers. Looking at the source code there is specific handling if the comparers of the two sets are the same https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,1476

Comment: @Charlieface the `Equals` works correctly. It's the `GetHashCode` that doesn't work ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GPNjjS)).

Comment: Fair enough that's just an out-and-out bug. FTR it's the same in .NET 7 and it seems they *want* the bug to be there https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/44c46e181a2a6f23a66f10924d8b7840150f18b7/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/HashSetEqualityComparer.cs#L66

Comment: @Charlieface yep, Microsoft love their bugs. They call them "by design", so they are here to stay. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `HashCode` struct to combine hashes. You need to sort it first in order to get a deterministic result, which is an expensive operation, so another hashcode combining method may be better.

```cs
var hs = new HashCode();
foreach (var item in yourHashSet.Order())
    hs.Add(item, yourHashSet.Comparer);

var hashCode = hs.ToHashCode();
```

You can also do this using an extension method, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71222930/14868997).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I have just run a test and yes it does produce different hashcodes for two HashSet<T>s that contain the same elements, that were added in different order

Comment: @TheodorZoulias True, I didn't realize it. Need to sort first, I have added this. But I like your answer better, I'm going to leave this one here for completeness

Comment: I don't think it compiles. The `Enumerable.Order` takes a `IComparer<T>`, and the `HashSet.Comparer` is `IEqualityComparer<T>`.